# Ubuntu 14.04 on Panda board

Tags: 14.04

How can I start egl services on Panda board Ubuntu 14.04 without X11?
Which package is responsible to do pvrsrvinit instead of glx support in older versions?
I have omap drm dkms module running and tested in Ubuntu 12.04 version

I tried running kmscube and I get this error message:

```
MESA-LOADER: malformed or no PCI ID
gbm: failed to open any driver (search paths /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri:${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)failed to load driver: omapdrm
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure now, but I recall these drivers were not in package, but were to be downloaded from Texas Instruments site for free, but in (appreciate that) in .msi installation file.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can you provide link? I can not find anything for OMAP PVR